# How can I tell the difference between granite and syenite?

Tags: geology, rocks, petrology, igneous

(I'm not a geologist, just helping my kids collect rocks).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is confusing - both rocks are commonly pink overall. But, granite has abundant quartz, syenite has no quartz to very little. Quartz will be the grey translucent mineral that looks just like a blob with no distinct shape.

You can use this website: https://www.virtualmicroscope.org to see examples of syenite and granite (use the search box).